# Why am i getting step by step waypoint instructions texts all over my map for Leaflet Routing Machine API implementation in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, routes, leaflet

I am trying to implement a simple map routing application in angular using Leaflet Routing Machine API.Here is my full angular component ts file code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import * as L from 'leaflet';
    import 'leaflet-routing-machine';

    interface CustomRoutingControlOptions extends L.Routing.RoutingControlOptions {
      createMarker?: (i: number, waypoint: L.Routing.Waypoint, n: number) => L.Marker<any>;
    }


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-route',
      templateUrl: './route.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./route.component.css']
    })
    export class RouteComponent implements OnInit {
      private map!: L.Map;
      private routingControl!: L.Routing.Control;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.map = L.map('map').setView([7.4, 80.7718], 9);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
        }).addTo(this.map);

        // Define the waypoints for the route
        const waypoints = [
          L.latLng(6.9271, 79.8612), // Colombo
          L.latLng(7.2097, 79.8449), // Negombo
          L.latLng(7.2906, 80.6337), // Kandy
          L.latLng(8.7518, 80.4988), // Vavuniya
          L.latLng(6.0535, 80.2200), // Galle
          L.latLng(8.5874, 81.2152),  // Trincomalee
          L.latLng(6.9271, 79.8612) // Colombo
        ];

        // Add a marker for the vehicle at Colombo location
        const truckIcon = L.icon({
          iconUrl: 'https://gizmobrewworks.com/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/truck3.png',
          iconSize: [25, 41],
          iconAnchor: [12, 41],
          popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
        });

        L.marker([6.9271, 79.8612], { icon: truckIcon })
          .bindPopup('Vehicle')
          .addTo(this.map);

        // Add routing control to the map
        L.Routing.control({
          waypoints: waypoints,
          routeWhileDragging: true,
          showAlternatives: true,
          addWaypoints: false,
          router: L.Routing.osrmv1({
            serviceUrl: 'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1'
          }),
        }).addTo(this.map);
      }
    }
```

I thought i would only get the routing displayed on map view. But i get step by step waypoint instruction text all over my map application. Someone help. Thanks in advance.